# How to give a ruby class more than one of same attribute

Tags: ruby

https://github.com/babycaseny/Learning-Ruby/blob/master/ex42-pet.rb

Sorry for being noob: But seems I am not able to look for an answer.

I am working on a ruby exercise about class and attributes using people and pets as an example.  I came to a question when answer the question about how to name the pet of Mary. "Well, Mary has a little lamb, right? How can I modify the class people so that it accept more than one pet for each person?"  I can just define a new class called "Lamb" which is " < Animal".  However, how can I modify "Person" so to accept more than one pet?

Comment: I think that we'll need to see your code first - please post it here.

Comment: there is not any class named People in the github code

Comment: Tip: Your pet attribute should be renamed to pets and should be initialized with an empty array.

Comment: My fault.  It is not "People" but "Person".

Comment: Do you mean in Line 47:

attr_accessor :pet

I shall convert :pet into some sort of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person

  def initialize(name)
    ## every person has a name
    @name = name

    ## Person may have many pets
    @pets = Array.new
  end

  attr_accessor :pets ## We can access attributes of their pets via the person
end
```

Comment: Succeed:

  mary = Person.new("Mary")
  stephy = Cat.new("Stephy")
  marylamb = Lamb.new("MaryLamb")
  mary.pets << stephy
  mary.pets << marylamb
  puts mary.pets
#<Cat:0x00000002996310>
#<Lamb:0x000000028e2900>
=> nil

Thx a lot, Emilliano and spickermann. :-D

Comment: The idiomatic way to write an empty `Array` is `[]`, not `Array.new`. And it is a very bad idea to expose internal state like that and have external clients fiddle with it directly. It should be the responsibility of a `Person` object to manage its `pets`, not some external object.

Comment: I agree. Please note that the current answer it's just a quick answer tip to a newbie question, and does not intend to be an authoritative essay on how the class should be implemented and expose their functionality.